# React Material UI - Bootstrap Container Equivalent

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, material-ui

Is theme a component in React Material UI which behaves like Bootstrap's `<div class="container">`?

I want it to have breakpoints (or at least a reasonable `max-width`).

I'm pretty sure it doesn't matter, but I want to use it with an `AppBar` and a `Drawer`.

Answer (score 4):

This is the css for bootstrap container. You can create one yourself and use it.

```
.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 750px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 970px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}
```

referenced from https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css

Comment: That was one of my ideas, it's just that it seems a little odd that there's no component to do that...

Comment: @AnDrOiD A lot of components that are available on bootstrap are missing in material UI. However, it is not surprising because Material UI started off with very different design principles. If you want some of the components from Bootstrap that does not exist in Material UI, only way is to create them yourself

Answer (score 2):

I personally have this implementation:

```
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const styles = theme => ({
    container: {
        paddingRight: 15,
        paddingLeft: 15,
        marginRight: 'auto',
        marginLeft: 'auto',

        // Full width for (xs, extra-small: 0px or larger) and (sm, small: 600px or larger)
        [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {  // medium: 960px or larger
            width: 920,
        },
        [theme.breakpoints.up('lg')]: {  // large: 1280px or larger
            width: 1170,
        },
        [theme.breakpoints.up('xl')]: {  // extra-large: 1920px or larger
            width: 1366,
        },
    },
});

const MyContainer = () => (
    <div className={styles.container}>
        {/* Other stuff here */}
    </div>
);

export default withStyles(styles)(MyContainer);
```

You can change width for each breakpoint according to your wish.